# Push animation without navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm beginner developer apps I have stroyboard with 2 UIViewController can how do a push animation without navigation bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a navigation bar for pushing. It is just a UI component.

You can choose to remove it by

> [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

`UINavigationController` is the stack which enables pushing.

Answer (score 0):

Hold the "control" key, and drag from viewControllerA to viewControllerB in the storyboard.

Comment: But only the model animation works the push is crash

Answer (score 0):

you need to embed your rootViewController into a NavigationController. Could make with storyboard. Click on your Controller. Editor -> Embed In -> NavigationController.
Then you can fire push-navigation.

```
UIViewController *controller = ...;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```